# uiwebview does not scroll till bottom

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, load, epub

i am new to iPad developer,

i am making ePub reader for my application, in which i am loading my ePub pages in `UIWebView`

when i load my pages in `webview` it scrolls unto some limits only,

here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...

    _webview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    _webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 770, 960);
    [_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    _webview.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:_webview];

    [self loadPage];
...
}



 - (void)loadPage{

  [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pagesPath]]];

    [self._webview sizeToFit];
    _webview.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
    _webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    _webview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

}
```

Comment: Please try to use the language conventions. Your code is hardly readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove All line and write only this lines,

```
_webview.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
_webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't scroll to the bottom end properly using `UIWebView`:

1) One  way (Programmatically) to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`.

```
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
```

[image]

2) Other way (Interface Builder)  to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`. Go to Interface Builder->Web View->Size Inspector and tick autosizing parts in all places (As seen on Image above)

Answer (score 0):

1)try to hide NavigationBar

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

2)Try to make WebViewScale to fit to View

```
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

3)Or may Be issue with Frame of WebView then Try

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
```